# LocalStorage HTML5

Tags: хранилище, html5

Как и где хранятся данные в локальном хранилище, предлагаемом новым стандартом - HTML5?
Так ли оно сходно с представлением Cookies?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что оно во многих смыслах круче и удобнее чем куки.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется или этот вопрос уже обсуждался?

> Как

http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

> где

Implementation specific. Многие вендоры выбрали SQLite по причине её лицензии.

> Так ли оно сходно с представлением Cookies?

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#history